# How to list all objects of a particular database in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, metadata

I would like to list all objects of a particular database in SQL Server. I created a query as shown below:

```
select name, type_desc from sys.objects 
WHERE type in ( 'C', 'D', 'F', 'L', 'P', 'PK', 'RF', 'TR', 'UQ', 'V', 'X' ) 
union
select name, type_desc from sys.indexes
order by name
```

However, this query list all objects of ALL databases rather than a particular database.

My question is: Is there a way to query all objects of just a particular database?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Which database are you running this in?  When I run it in a particular database, I don't get anything outside that database.

Comment: Thanks. My mistake. I can get objects of a particular database.

Answer (score 8):

List all procs, views, tables, functions in Sql Server:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       o.name AS Object_Name,
       o.type_desc
  FROM sys.sql_modules m
       INNER JOIN
       sys.objects o
         ON m.object_id = o.object_id
 --WHERE  '.' + m.definition + '.' LIKE '%[^a-z]employeeid[^a-z]%'
 order by type_desc, object_name
```

The comment is if you want to search for a particular (whole) word.

Comment: *within a database. This won't search all databases, just the scope of the current database.

Comment: @chadwin that's actually what he wanted

Answer (score 8):

This is what I use.

```
  SELECT  o.type_desc AS Object_Type
       ,  s.name AS Schema_Name
       ,  o.name AS Object_Name
    FROM  sys.objects o 
    JOIN  sys.schemas s
      ON  s.schema_id = o.schema_id
   WHERE  o.type NOT IN ('S'  --SYSTEM_TABLE
                        ,'PK' --PRIMARY_KEY_CONSTRAINT
                        ,'D'  --DEFAULT_CONSTRAINT
                        ,'C'  --CHECK_CONSTRAINT
                        ,'F'  --FOREIGN_KEY_CONSTRAINT
                        ,'IT' --INTERNAL_TABLE
                        ,'SQ' --SERVICE_QUEUE
                        ,'TR' --SQL_TRIGGER
                        ,'UQ' --UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT
                        )
ORDER BY  Object_Type
       ,  SCHEMA_NAME
       ,  Object_Name
```